# Android App Widget

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I just wanna ask regarding android widget. I'm done creating  the app widget to my application and I am asking if android widget has a way of delaying right after clicking/tapping the button. It is like after clicking or tapping the button if there is a notice that will appear if it has been tapped too much wait for 10 seconds. thanks for the reply in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store when the next valid click is in a member variable

```
// create a static to store valid click time
private static long nextValidTime = new Date().getTime();

    // ... snip ...

    // inside your onClick listener
    if (nextValidTime >= Date().getTime()) {
        nextValidTime = new Date().getTime() + 10;
        // doSomething
    } else {
        // show dialogue that click was too soon   
    }
```